# Jquery array get item x to item y

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I'm struggeling to iterate over an array in a certain way. I've read numerous posts here but just can't get it to work.

I have an array called `art_stuff` like this:

```
[
  {
    "block": 0,
    "amt": 5
  },
  {
    "block": 1,
    "amt": 1
  },
  {
    "block": 2,
    "amt": 2
  },
  {
    "block": 3,
    "amt": 3
  },
  {
    "block": 4,
    "amt": 4
  }
]
```

And a JSON response like this:

```
"products":[{
  "id":1, //0
  "id":2, //1 
  "id":3, //2 
  "id":4, //3 
  "id":5, //4 
  "id":6, //5 
  "id":7, //6
   etc ....
```

In the `$.each` I first loop over the array. The `amt` in the array is the amount of id's I need from the JSON response. So for example:

- `Block 0` needs 5 id's from the JSON response. So that's index 0 - 4 (= id 1 to id 5)
- `Block 1` needs 1 id, start at where block 0 stopped, so that's index 5 (= id 6)
- `Block 2` needs 2 id's, start at where block 1 stopped, so that's index 6 - 7 (= id 7 and id 8)
  etc....

So basically each each block starts looping at where the previous block stopped.

So for example:

```
$.getJSON(url-to-json, function(data) {
  ........

  var start_count = 0 
  var end_count = 0

  $.each(art_stuff, function(index, art_block){

   start_count = start_count + art_block.amt 
   end_count = start_count + 1

   console.log('block_' + art_block.block + ' starts at: ' + start_count + ', and ends at: ' + end_count)

  //var prods = data.products.slice(start_count, end_count)
```

Expected result would be:

```
block_0 starts at: 0, and ends at: 4
block_1 starts at: 5, and ends at: 5
block_2 starts at: 6, and ends at: 7
block_3 starts at: 8, and ends at: 10
etc...
```

I don't understand how to create a proper start and end point to slice the JSON response.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your `products` is absolutely invalid. You're overriding the `"id"` property always to the latest entry value. That's wrong. Learn how JSON or Object properties work. The property is expected to be unique, otherwise the latest entry with the same propertyName will have precedence.

Comment: is the problem that you are not able to slice  the `"products"` member of the response? Because the formatting of that object makes no sense, if you have the multiple members with the same name (`id` in your case) in the same object then you just override them and end up with the last one. It's not a valid object

Comment: I think the "products" part is not relevant to the actual question (at least at this stage, will be relevant later) - the issue is working out which indices to use for `.slice()` (as mentioned by OP) - implying that the `products` is an array and perhaps just miscommunicated in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change these two lines:

```
   start_count = start_count + art_block.amt 
   end_count = start_count + 1
```

to

```
   end_count = start_count + art_block.amt - 1
```

then at the end of your `$.each` add

```
   start_count = end_count + 1;
```

Together, giving:

```js
var art_stuff = [{
    "block": 0,
    "amt": 5
  },
  {
    "block": 1,
    "amt": 1
  },
  {
    "block": 2,
    "amt": 2
  },
  {
    "block": 3,
    "amt": 3
  },
  {
    "block": 4,
    "amt": 4
  }
]
var start_count = 0
var end_count = 0

$.each(art_stuff, function(index, art_block) {

  end_count = start_count + art_block.amt - 1;

  console.log('block_' + art_block.block + ' starts at: ' + start_count + ', and ends at: ' + end_count)

  //... other code

  start_count = end_count + 1; // ready for next iteration

}); // end of $.each
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I also wanted to mention that the `products` object that OP wants to slice seems problematic: it has the same `id` property multiple times.

Comment: @Aioros yes, looks like that should be an array of IDs rather than a single entry/index array, eg `products":[ { "id":"1" }, { "id":"2" }...`

Comment: Correctemundo!!! Exactly what I needed! Completely overlooked to add the +1 at the end. Thx

Comment: Glad to help.  The key is to set the *next* start at the end of the previous one.